# How to make sure there's one space in HTML before every "<" and after ">"

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a diff algorithm which compares words. Problems arise when words touch tags as in the example:

`<strong>Word`

In this case it thinks that `<strong>Word` is only one word, because there is no space between tag and word. (Rich text editors don't guarantee a space between word and tag)

How do I make sure there is only one space (not to duplicate spaces if there is one already) before every tag starting `<` and ending `>`

I have a code which does exactly that for `<p>` tag, but I don't know how to modify regex so it fixes all tags.

Code for `<p>` tags:

```
    $text = preg_replace_callback("!<p>([\S])!", function ($p) {
        return "<p> " . $p[1];
    }, $text);
    $text = preg_replace_callback("!([\S])</p>!", function ($p) {
        return $p[1] . " </p>";
    }, $text);
```

Comment: I think you need `"!(\S)(</[^<]+>)!"` and replace with `$1 $2` and then use  `"!(<(?!/)[^<]+>)(\S)!"` and replace with `"$1 $2"`

Comment: `str_replace(array(">", "> "), "> ", $string)` ??

Comment: @stribizhev Unknown modifier '/' in second case

Comment: Ah, yes, replace the `!` delimiters with `~`. And use single quotes rather than double quotes around.

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but if you have control over your diff algorithm, can you not just include `<` and `>` as word separators? It's perfectly valid (and I'd say better) to not have these spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the work :

```
<?php
  $text = preg_replace_callback("!(<[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)([\S])!", function ($p) {
    return $p[1] . " " . $p[2];
  }, $text);
  $text = preg_replace_callback("!([\S])(</[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)!", function ($p) {
    return $p[1] . " " . $p[2];
  }, $text);
?>
```

Where you catch with `(</[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)` any possible html tag (according to [tag names specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#tag-name)).